# keep the longest possible url from a list and delete others with php

Tags: php, windows, string, directory, dos

I have a notepad file with a lot (and I do mean a lot) of urls in there. Most of the paths are duplicates, that is, for one additional folder jump, another item was created in the list. What I want to do is to keep the longest url in a list for a specific folder id, say 993999, and delete the rest of urls that have the same id. all of my urls have unique numbered folder like 993999. But I don't know how to achieve this. Any help is much appreciated.

P.S: I was also wondering if it was possible to do this with DOS? Maybe it will be easier for windows? Not sure about it though.

Comment: Do you need this to be done just one time or periodically?

Comment: periodically.. actually i generated a file with list of all my sub directories path but it generates something like

D:\winwamp\www\info\956085\Giuliana_and_Bill\season_1
D:\winwamp\www\info\956085\Giuliana_and_Bill\season_1\episode_2
D:\winwamp\www\info\956085\Giuliana_and_Bill\season_1\episode_2\Suburbs_or_the_City

so i need to is to just keep the last one not other two, to be precious i need the directory path which dont have any more sub directory..